# Return statements are not returning the output in correct format

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Computes and returns the Date on which Thanksgiving will fall 
 * in a given year.
 *
 * NOTE: By law, Thanksgiving is the 4th Thursday in November
 *
 * @param year the year for which to compute the date of Thanksgiving
 * @return the Date of Thanksgiving for the specified year
 */

     public Date getThanksgiving(int year)
     {    

        int weekcount = 0 ; // record the amount of weeks that has passed  

        Date thanksgiving = new Date (11 , 1 , year) ;

        while ( weekcount < 4 )
           {
              thanksgiving.next(); // add one to date 

          if (thanksgiving.getDayOfWeek().equals("Thursday"))// check if the day of week is Thursday 
           {
               weekcount++ ;    // add one to weekcount 
           }           

           if (weekcount == 4)
           {

           System.out.println(thanksgiving.getLongDate());

           } 


           }  



           return thanksgiving ;
     }
```

I am not supposed to have that println statement instead i am supposed to return the correct date using the return statement. The problem is that I am getting this "Date@2f4d3709" as my output. 
Date class-- http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~shawg/2210/Date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns a `Date` object and since `toString()` is not implemented in your class, printing the object will have a format like "Date@2f4d3709" when doing something like

```
System.out.println(getThanksgiving(2014));
```

instead you have to call `getLongDate()` to get a formated string to print

```
System.out.println(getThanksgiving(2014).getLongDate());
```

Comment: It is unclear to me if he talking about the output from the `println` in the code excerpt or a `println` (not shown) being run on the return from the given method? If its the former `Date` is implemented incorrectly or the code as shown does not match runtime. If it is the latter then this answer is correct. +1 to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I mentioned my full output. The println statement is correct, I get the proper date. The error is in the return statement. That is when I get "Date@2f4d3709". My question is if I can fix the return statement so I can get the proper date from it, because I am not supposed to get my output from a println statement.

Comment: You could change the return type to `String` and return `thanksgiving.getLongDate()` instead. Or work with your `Date` object after returning it.

Comment: I cannot change the return type to string, because the instructor specified that the method heading has to look like that. Is there any other way that I can fix my return statement?

Comment: No, not really. It's correct. What you're doing with the returned object seems to be wrong.

Comment: You were right. I did something wrong with the returned object. Thanks so much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to call [`PrintStream.println()` with an `Object` argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object)), that object will be converted to a `String` using [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). Since your `Date` class does not override `toString()`, the default implementation provided by `java.lang.Object` will be used.

You can solve this three ways.

1. You need to call your `Date.getLongDate()` method and pass the value returned to your output, instead of the entire object.
2. Change the return of `getThanksgiving(int)` to a String and return `Date.getLongDate()`
3. Override `toString()` in your `Date` class as below.

Example:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return getLongDate();
}
```

Comment: So, there is no way for me to use the return statement to get the date.

Comment: @Name Show me the implementation of `Date`, and I'll be able to tell you.